# How does Desmos get $\displaystyle\iint_{[-1,0]^2}(xy)!dxdy\approx0.932405138093$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I was messing around in the [Desmos $3$D calculator](https://www.desmos.com/3d) when I decided to plot $f(x,y)=(xy)!$, and noticed something strange. Looking at the top view of the graph (as you can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/3d/1a6466a33d)), it seemed to be defined on $[-1,1]$ for both $x$ and $y$, even if $x$ or $y$ were greater than $0$ with the other variable being $-1$. Now, just to make sure, I decided to set up the integral$$\iint_{[-1,0]^2}(xy)!dxdy$$and not only can Desmos integrate it, its value seems to be approximately $0.932405138093$. Now, I know that this integral can be represented as$$\iint_{-1}^0\int_1^\infty e^{-t}t^{xy}dt+\sum_{k\ge0}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!(1+k+xy)}dxdy$$using$$x!:=\int_1^\infty e^{-t}t^xdt+\sum_{k\ge0}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!(1+k+x)}$$but I'm still unsure how such an integral can be evaluated.

---

#### My question

---

How does Desmos get $\displaystyle\iint_{[-1,0]^2}(xy)!dxdy\approx0.932405138093$?

Comment: It's presumably interpreting $(xy)!$ as the $\Gamma$-function $\Gamma(xy + 1)$, which is well defined for $xy\not = -1, -2, \dots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments, @anomaly gave the answer.

You could even using series expansion considering
$$\Gamma(t+1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,t^n$$
$$\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^0 \Gamma(xy+1)\,dx\,dy=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^0 (x y)^n\,dx\,dy=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{(n+1)^2}$$

Truncating the initial series to $O(t^{26})$ gives $0.931694$.

**Edit**

If, instead of series, we use the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ of $\Gamma(t+1)$ such as
$$P_1=\frac {1+\frac{\left(\pi^2-6 \gamma ^2\right) }{12 \gamma
   }t } {1+\frac{\left(\pi^2+6 \gamma ^2\right) }{12 \gamma
   }t }$$

whose error is $\sim \frac 34t^3$ (for $P_2$, the error drops down to $\frac{5}{183} t^5$)

With this kind of expressions, the problem is not bad at all. For example

$$\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^0 P_1\,dx\,dy=
\frac{\pi ^4-36 \gamma ^3 \left(4 \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{6 \gamma
   ^2+\pi ^2}{12 \gamma }\right)+\gamma \right)}{\left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi^2\right)^2}$$

Tedious partial fraction decompositions for sure but, converted to decimals, interesting numbers.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^0 P_n\,dx\,dy\\
 1 & 0.91373748 \\
 2 & 0.93216913 \\
 3 & 0.93244576 \\
 4 & 0.93240460 \\
 5 & 0.93240459 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$